# Can we detect the number of View Components used on a screen

Tags: android, object, view, apk

Can we detect the number of View Components like TextView, Button etc used on a screen when we launch any application?
If yes, how to do so. I am talking about a third party app. I want to know the number of such objects used on a particular screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a uiautomator view that comes with the sdk tools.

Go to sdk/tools and there you will the uiautomatorview which is a windows batch file. On the top left there is a button to grab screen shot.

Inbox screenshot

[image]

Comment: @milez give it a try. I have tried with google apps and few other apps. I guess it should